# How to get a file in a S3 bucket that was uploaded using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently trying to implement Cloudfront upload (POST/PUT methods) on an existing S3 bucket.

My Cloudfront distribution seems well-configured.
I am using Cloudfront signed urls to upload my files in the S3 bucket. It works fine.
Once the files uploaded, I can access them using Cloudfront signed url. It is fine too.

But I observe that I cannot access the uploaded files (via Cloudfront) using the AWS credentials (access_key_id & secret_key).
Everytime, I try this, I receive an AccessDenied error code.

I feel like something is missing in the configuration of the S3 bucket policy.
Here is my current S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Did I miss something or is it just impossible?

Comment: You definitely missed something, though not really related to what you are trying to do.  Allowing PutObject for Principal "`*`" is an *unimaginably insecure* configuration, and you're doing the same thing for GetObject fot something you are calling "private" content?  With that config, it seems like it would be hard to say what is actually working (correctly) and what's just blindly being permitted for reasons other than you intended.

Comment: My bad, this was not the Principal value of my S3 policy. Please check my post update.

Comment: This documentation explain what I want to do: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html. But I want the implementation of the point 1 without the implementation of the point 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have the same issue once.

Try to add the header "**x-amz-acl=bucket-owner-full-control**" to the upload request and that should do the trick.